# Kernelize Linear Regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, kernel-trick, ridge-regression, supervised-learning

We can kernelize Ridge regression as shown in these notes: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/Kernel-Ridge.pdf.

However would it be possible to find a vector $\boldsymbol\alpha$ such that we can express linear regression as $$f(\mathbf x)=\sum_{i=1}^N \alpha_i \kappa(\mathbf x,\mathbf x_i)$$
where $\mathbf x\in \mathbb R^N$, and $\kappa:\mathbb R^N\times \mathbb R^N\mapsto  \mathbb R$ is a positive semi definite kernel (*i.e.* kernelize linear regression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "linear regression" you mean unregularized linear regression, i.e. ordinary least squares. In that case, then yes, sure: this is just ridge regression with $\lambda = 0$. If the kernel matrix $K$ is invertible, then everything still works.

In fact, for many popular choices of kernel (such as the Gaussian RBF), the matrix $K$ is *guaranteed* to be invertible. But this is true only in exact arithmetic; in practice, the trailing eigenvalues of $K$ will be far too close to zero for computer arithmetic to handle them properly, and you'll get *extreme* numerical instability. You'll also be extremely close to severe [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity), so that numerically you'll run into all the same problems there (which are often addressed by ridge regression).

Comment: Ok thanks but how do you suggest to proceed? Because if we set $\lambda=0 $ and do as in ridge regression we'll stumble through a $1/\lambda$...

Comment: If you derive as in (4)-(7) of your linked note, you don't need a $1/\lambda$. (The "alternative derivation" would need to be changed here, because there's no constraint to put in the Lagrangian.)